# How to create generic service using Vue3 Js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I am working on an application where I am trying to implement common functions which will call an API endpoint here is my implementation using vue3.

> Page

```
<script>

import httpService from "./services/HttpService.vue";

export default {
 data() {
  return {
   weather: undefined,
   error : false,
   errormessage : "",
  };
 },
 methods :  {

async fetchWeather(e) {
  if (e.key == "Enter" && this.query) {
    let {response} =await get(query,`${weather_url}forecast?city=`);  //await axios.get(`${this.url_base}forecast?city=${this.query}`);
    this.setResults(response.data);
  }else if (e.key == "Enter" && !this.query){
    this.error = true;
    this.errormessage = 'Please enter name to search!';
  }
},
setResults(res) {
 if(res.isSuccessful === true){
    this.error = false;
    this.weather = res.response;
 }else{
    this.weather = undefined;
    this.errormessage = res.response;
    this.error = true;
 }
}
},
};

</script>
```

> Service

```
<script>

import axios from "axios";

export default async function GenericService() {
  async function get(query,url) {
    try {
      let response = await axios.get(`${base_url}${url}${this.query}`);
      return response;
    } catch (err) {
      throw new Error(err);
    }
  }
}

</script>
```

> GlobalUrl

```
<script>
export const ConstantBaseUrl = {
  base_url: "https://localhost:7005/",
};

export const EndPointUrl = {
  weather_url : "api/weather/"
}


</script>
```

Here I want to achieve is there must be a common method that will be used to send a get request to my backend API. My code is not working and I know I am I might be missing something or doing it the wrong way because I am totally new to Vue3.js.

Comment: Hi, could you please elaborate on `My code is not working`?

Comment: For starters, it doesn't make sense to put a service into .vue SFC file. It's not a component. GenericService doesn't return anything. It's unclear why it's supposed to be a function. In case you need a namespace to contain service members, JS module already provides it

Comment: @kissu means it doesn't find the get method

Comment: @EstusFlask can you please let me the correct solution

Comment: I can't provide a solution. The question doesn't contain enough information. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I am basically looking for a common component in which I can write some common reuse methods and constants